# How to make a instagram account via python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, header, instagram

Im working on a larger project that will use this feature of making a Instagram account. So far i get the server to understand my reqeust though it wont make a account. I assume im missing some info in the request but im not sure.

```py
def main():
    username = ""
    password = ""
    email_to_use = ""
    first_name = ""

    time = str(int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()))
    enc_password = f"#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{time}:{password}"
    session = requests.Session()
    # set a cookie that signals Instagram the "Accept cookie" banner was closed
    session.cookies.set("ig_cb", "2")
    session.headers.update({'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.114 Safari/537.36'})
    session.headers.update({'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com'})
    res = session.get('https://www.instagram.com')

    csrftoken = None
    for key in res.cookies.keys():
        if key == 'csrftoken':
            csrftoken = session.cookies['csrftoken']
    session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken})

    login_data = {'username': username, 'enc_password': enc_password, 'email': email_to_use, 'first_name': first_name,}


    login = session.post('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/web_create_ajax/attempt/', data=login_data, allow_redirects=True)
    session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': login.cookies['csrftoken']})

    cookies = login.cookies
    print(login.text)
```

that code returns

```
{"account_created":false,"dryrun_passed":true,"username_suggestions":["jsonhews","floristry_zrpc","jsonhews2","jsonhews43","jsonhews524","jsonhews3154","jsonhews7","jsonhews64","jsonhews356","jsonhews2146","jsonhews3"],"status":"ok"}
```

Not sure what i could do so if you have any ideas id love to hear! Thanks.

Comment: The dryrun_passed is True which means you passed the first step of filling email, username, firstname and password. This means that you should now send another request for setting the birthday and then the last one is the email verification system. That's what I found using Postman

Answer (score -1):

Based on the JSON response, it looks like maybe you're trying to send a username that's already taken. Try using one that you're certain is unique and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: after playing with it some that doesn't seem to be the issue. I guess the username suggestion response is by default. something Interesting though is when i send a request missing important data such as email it responds with this

```{"account_created": false, "errors": {"email": [{"message": "This field is required.", "code": "email_required"}]}, "dryrun_passed": false, "username_suggestions": ["jsonhews", "jsonhews7", "jsonhews66", "jsonhews410", "jsonhews5905", "jsonhews2", "jsonhews75", "jsonhews559"], "status": "ok", "error_type": "form_validation_error"}```

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me too. I am also writing a bot to create an Instagram account with Selenium, and when the bot enters the code sent to the email and clicks the next button, it returns the same values, and I checked and found that these accounts have been created. But once I logged in with the same username and password, I found that these accounts were detected as bots and suspended.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).